# Alternative solution.

Tags: extremal-combinatorics

can we find an alternative solution to the problem which states that we have to find the maximum number of intersections of lines connecting points lying on plane such that no three points lie on a straight line and no third point between two alternate points lies towards the interior of the line connecting those alternate points . We have to find an expression for any number of points greater than equal to 4 as there is 1 for a quadrilateral 5 for a pentagon 15 for a hexagon 30 for a heptagon 70 for an octagon ...
also we have a restriction we are not allowed to solve this by finding the number of ways of choosing any four points lying on the line as we have to find an alternative solution .I have an expression in mind which correctly determines these for any number of points  but i have to post it somewhere else. please write what you think.

Comment: please dont read this if you are finding a solution on your own an alternative one other than the mentioned above of course . letting number of points be n and sigma  summation variable be k mine is:- sigma summation of k from 1 to n-3 of n-1-kC2 i found this after

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000332

Comment: No comment about this rich reference ?